# Language that supports serializing coroutines

Tags: serialization, programming-languages, dsl, coroutine

I don't think such support exists in current languages. I think what I want to do could be solved by a "workflow engine". But the problem I have with workflow's is generally they are:

1. Declarative/verbose and I find a imperative style much more succinct
2. Heavyweight, I'll have a lot of simple though diverse little state machines

I've investigated [serializing iterators in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321827/serializing-anonymous-delegates-in-c) but that doesn't get me exactly where I want to be. I'm current looking at putting together a DSL in [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) but not sure if I'll be able to get coroutine-like behaviour into Boo, and be able to serialize it as well.

### Example

Here is limited fictional example of what I'd like to do. The main issue is that at any point in a routine you may need to get user input. The time between inputs could be very long so the state of service will need to be serialized to disk.

```
    def RunMachine(user)
      var lever = user.ChooseLever()
      lever.Pull()
      var device = CreateDevice(user)
      machine.Add(device)
      machine.Run()

   def CreateDevice(user)
      var color = user.ChooseColor()
      var shape = user.ChooseShape()
      return Device(color, shape)
```

## Update

I have a working "engine" in CPython. It piggy-backs on the iterator/yield support in python. So code looks like this:

```
def escape(self, you):        
    roll = yield self.game.rollDice(you)
    if roll < 5:
        self.caughtAction(you)
```

Where `rollDice` can be interrupted. with some user action. **CPython** however doesn't serialize iterators.

Since the whole state of the game can be defined as a sequence of commands, I serialize the game state up to the point at where a coroutine started then the remaining list of commands. So to save/restore looks like this:

```
def dumpGameState(game):
    if gameState.partialState:
        return pickle.dumps({ 'partialState': game.partialState, 'partialInputs': game.partialInputs })

    return pickle.dumps(game)

def loadGameState(data):
    state = pickle.loads(data)

    if state.__class__ is Game:
        return state

    r = pickle.loads(state['partialState'])

    for input in state['partialInputs']:
        game.execute(**input)   
    return game
```

### Current Investigations

I still find this unsatisfactory. As I end up having to use 'yield' on almost every method. I'd rather not have to specifically decorate a method. Also it quite fails at serialization.

Currently I'm investigating going a functional route, as functional languages seem to have better support for metaprogramming/DSL creation. Currently looking at

- [F# Computational Expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions#Defining_Computation_Expressions)
- Haskell

I'm hopeful that with strong enough metaprogramming facilities I can automate the state storage mechanism. Also, if I go the F# route, I'm pretty sure I can fall back on the ["technique"/(hack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321827/serializing-anonymous-delegates-in-c) I used to serialize iterators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny that you should ask this today, and then later I read about [Continuations in Mono](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Apr-09.html). Looks like the kind of thing you're after. In particular there's a reference to [Microthreading in Second Life](http://secondlife.blogs.com/babbage/2006/05/microthreading_.html), including this description:

> SecondLife required that code be
>   suspended at any point in time and
>   that its entire state be serializable
>   into a format suitable for storage
>   into a database. Serialized state
>   could then be restored at a different
>   point in time or on a different
>   computer (for example while moving
>   from node to node).

Unless I've misunderstood you, this could be a good avenue to explore.

Comment: This looks great, or at least it has the best potential. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've found the best support for serializing [coroutines](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial) appears to be in Lua via the [Pluto](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary) library.

I triend [Mono 2.6](http://www.mono-project.com/Continuations), but couldn't get coroutines working. I then experimented with Python/IronPython for awhile, but serialization support was lacking.

Now with Lua I'll have to [interface via P/Invoke from .NET to Lua](http://ttuxen.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/embedding-lua-in-dotnet/) which prove to be a challenge to get working on both Linux and Windows, but ultimately if I'm looking for a scripting language to support a game, probably best to use what is already popularly being chosen.

**Update**

I ended up abandoning Lua for the time being. I was getting too bogged down in integration issues. I went back to Python. I'm using [python yield expressions](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) for my coroutines, and working around the issue that [pickle doesn't support generators](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

In my case, the program state doesn't always have active coroutines, which means sometimes I can pickle the state. Otherwise I store the last pickle state, and a 'replay history' of the actions since. Then restoring state is just unpickling the last state, and replaying any actions.

Comment: I recently got pluto and lua working in my continuation serialization game engine (http://weaverengine.com).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Windows Workflow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx

It is meant to be used in a manner like this, with the ability to persist a workflow if there is inactivity on it, as well as the ability to restart it.

While technically it isn't language support, it should get the job done.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to specifically point out I was trying to avoid a XML heavy, declaritive work flow engine, eg. specifically Windows Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)?

> In any language which supports closures, it is possible to write programs in continuation passing style and manually implement call/cc.

`call/cc` being `call-with-current-continuation`.

Comment: I believe coroutines are something you could build on top of continuations. Coroutines allow for a much more natural expression of intent IMHO.

Comment: But I return to the issue, even given continuation support in a language, can you serialize them?

Comment: Some.  For example, http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations#head-d6b2435bbd91bef7f61324cd35775998da035f7a

Comment: In fact, the design of the http://www.seaside.st/ Seaside web framework depends upon serializable continuations.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Java includes Rhino, a javascript interpreter with support for serializeable continuations. There's also Pluto+Lua, which I'm investigating now.

I'd like to hear about what path you ended up taking, as serializeable continuations are important to the http://weaverengine.com project.

Comment: Updated question with where I'm currently at.

Comment: I ended up using Pluto and Lua 5.1 with good success. There's also Eris for Lua 5.2, but I haven't given that a try yet.