# Serializing a list of anonymous delegates

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, anonymous-methods, anonymous-class

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321827/serializing-anonymous-delegates-in-c) may be very similar to my one, but I cannot see the answer I need in it. I have a class, called `CASM`, that has a `List<Action>`. I want to serialize this class (using the `BinaryFormatter` or something similar). This class and all classes referenced in the `Action`s have got correct `[Serializable]` and `[NonSerializable]` attributes.

The problem comes when serialization is attempted - it gives this error:

```
Type 'CASM.CASM+<>c__DisplayClass2c' in Assembly 'CASM, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

This `<>c__DisplayClass2c` is an autogenerated internal class that holds the different types of anonymous delegate I am using in my application. However, as we can see from the below image, it is not `[Serializable]`:

[alt text http://bayimg.com/image/maebbaacj.jpg](http://bayimg.com/image/maebbaacj.jpg)

What would be the best way to change my application so this does work? Make my own `<>c__DisplayClass2c`-type class and make it serializable? Or is there a better way?

---

**EDIT:** In the end I just made my own class, instead of the autogenerated one. I helps with debugging as well, actually having a descriptive name rather than just `b__12()`.

Comment: You say the class is autogenerated -- how is it done?  Do control it?  Is it generated by a 3rd party component?

Comment: It is autogenerated by the compiler - it has the [CompilerGenerated] attribute. I think it is just a class/place to store a number of very similar anonymous delegates (they are all void and accept a string[] as a parameter in this case).

Comment: Then yeah, try generating your own class.  You may also have a problem with anonymous methods (I haven't tried it, so I don't know), in which case, try non-anonymous versions.  If even that doesn't work, you could try turning the methods into expressions first (those _should_ be serializable)

Comment: Compiling Expression trees run into the exact same problem as Actions you still need to make the autogenerated class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually makes very little sense to serialize a delegate. Normally, you would choose to mark delegate fields as `[NonSerialized]`, and recreate it when needed. If your main intent *is* to store the delegates, then I would recommend thinking of a completely different approach, frankly.

Additionally, note that `BinaryFormatter` is brittle if you are planning to keep the data for any length of time (but acceptable for transient data)

To look further, I suspect we'd need to look at some reproducible code.

---

Update: actually, I suspect you *could* serialize it by writing your own explicit capture classes (rather than the compiler-generated ones). But I still think the concept is fundamentally flawed. And writing capture classes by hand isn't fun.

---

To address the points in comments; re long term storage - because it is [so darned brittle](http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html&ei=JV_jSu-XMNWy4QbMkuCGAg&sa=X&oi=nshc&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CA0QzgQoAA&usg=AFQjCNHePNfO-kC5agrK0GZJS-erzb-LUw) - something as simple as changing from:

```
public int Value {get;set;}
```

to

```
private int value;
public int Value {
    get {return value;}
    set {
        if(value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

will destroy serialization; as will changing assemblies, type names, "looking at it funny", etc.

Re the delegates; to give an example of a manual capture; instead of:

```
int i = ...
Predicate<Foo> test = delegate (Foo x) { return x.Bar == i;}
```

you might do:

```
int i = ...
MyCapture cpt = new MyCapture(i);
Predicate<Foo> test = cpt.MyMethod;
```

with

```
[Serializable]
class MyCapture {
    private int i;
    public MyCapture(int i) {this.i = i;}
    public bool MyMethod(Foo x) {return x.Bar == i;}
}
```

As you can see - not always trivial (this is the simplest of examples).

Comment: I knew a comment like this was coming - it does seem to be a very strange thing to do. However, delegates seem to be the best (or at least fastest) method for what I am trying to do. Creating the delegates takes a (relatively) long time, so it would be good if I could store them. I've now realised after looking at Expression Tree from Nader Shirazie's comment that I am essentially trying to recreate a limited Expression Tree system/syntax (ie building up code from delegates). And why is BinaryFormatter bad for long term storage of data?

Comment: Ah, thanks. So another system like protobuf-net or XML wouldn't have this "brittle" problem as they don't store types/versions/assemblies etc?

Comment: Exactly; most serializers only store the *data*; this makes it implementation independent, and generally shorter. `BinaryFormatter` stores type/field information, which is **very** implementation specific.