# How do delegates get serialized

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates, binaryformatter

I know that you can serialize a delegate like such:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public Func<int,int> Del;
}
...
public static void WriteFoo(Foo foo)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, foo);
    }
}
```

But what will happen to objects that the function contains, for example, in this case:

```
int D = 10;
Func<int, int> del = x => x * x - D;
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Del = del;
WriteFoo(f);
```

What will happen to `D`? 
Will the value of `D` be preserved? 
What will happen if `D` is an object reference?

Comment: Side note: you may want to try it first yourself and than see if you need explanations...

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132702/could-we-save-delegates-in-a-file-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618530/serializing-a-list-of-anonymous-delegates