# LINQ: How to return different field than used by min()

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I'm working with an IEnumerable Dictionary `(data.Tags)` inside a List `(masterList)`.

Here is a typical query I'm doing (which works):

```
var tagList = 
    (from data in masterList
    from tag in data.Tags
    where tag.id == 0x10
    select tag).Distinct(new TagComparer());
```

The `tag` class has fields `Id`, `Value` and `TranslatedValue`. I want to search based on `Id`, use `Value` to determine which is the minimum and then return the `TranslatedValue` (instead of `Value`).

All of my attempts thus far throw an ArgumentException, such as this:

```
var tagList = 
    (from data in masterList
    from tag in data.Tags
    where tag.id == 0x10
    select new
    {
       tag.Value,
       tag.TranslatedValue
    };
return tagList.Min().TranslatedValue;
```

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: What is `.Min()` expected to be? How is the compiler expected to determine it?

Comment: As stated above, _use `Value` to determine which is the minimum_. As for how, that's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` to order the elements in ascending order (putting the minimum value at the first position), `Select` to get your translated value, and then `First` to take that minimum element:

```
var minVal = (from data in masterList 
             from tag in data.Tags
             where tag.id == 0x10
             select tag)
             .Distinct(new TagComparer())
             .OrderBy(t => t.Value) // lowest value will be first in the list
             .First() // take the first element, which is the min
             .TranslatedValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `IComparable<T>` for your tag class, and base the comparison on the `Value` property. Then instead of selecting the minimum `Value` you can select the minimum tag and take the `TranslatedValue` from that.

Some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
class tag : IComparable<tag>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int TranslatedValue { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(tag other)
    {
        if (other.Value > this.Value)
            return -1;
        if (other.Value < this.Value)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id:{0}, Value: {1}, TranslatedValue: {2}", Id, Value, TranslatedValue);
    }
}
```

That set your tag class up to implement `IComparable<T>`. To use it to get the `TranslatedValue` it's as simple as:

```
int minTranslatedValue = tags.Min().TranslatedValue;
```

Where `tags` is some sort of `IEnumerable<Tag>` collection.

Answer (score 1):

My answer when I encountered this exact problem before was a little more involved than the others here, but it works very well in these situations and is a little more performant; develop an ObjectWithMin() extension method that will return the entire object that contains the minimum value of a specified projection. Here's a basic algorithm; it iterates the enumerable only once and executes linearly instead of in nlogn-time:

```
public static T ObjectWithMin<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, TResult> projection)
        where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
    {
        if (elements == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elements", "Sequence is null.");
        if (!elements.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequence contains no elements.");

        var seed = elements.Select(t => new { Object = t, Projection = projection(t) }).First();

        return elements.Aggregate(seed,
                                  (s, x) =>
                                  projection(x).CompareTo(s.Projection) < 0
                                      ? new {Object = x, Projection = projection(x)}
                                      : s
            ).Object;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var tagList = 
    (from data in masterList
    from tag in data.Tags
    where tag.id == 0x10
    select new
    {
       tag.Value,
       tag.TranslatedValue
    };
return tagList.ObjectWithMin(x=>x.Value).TranslatedValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [custom MinElement extension that was posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645644/whats-your-favorite-linq-to-objects-operator-which-is-not-built-in/3645724#3645724)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort by one property, take the first item, and get another property:

```
return
  masterList
  .SelectMany(data => data.Tags)
  .Where(tag => tag.id == 0x10)
  .OrderBy(tag => tag.Value)
  .First()
  .TranslatedValue;
```

Comment: Wouldn't OrderByDescending put the Max Value in the first position (I think he wants OrderBy which does Ascending order).

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Yes, you are right. I was thinking backwards. :P It should of course be `OrderBy`.