# Interesting IEnumerable (or IQueryable) Extension Methods

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

Has anyone written some interesting or cool Linq extension methods they would like to share? I'm attempting to build up a library of such methods for our developers, to help them transition into Linq and away from T-SQL.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Related: Whats your favorite LINQ to Objects operator which is not built in? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645644/whats-your-favorite-linq-to-objects-operator-which-is-not-built-in

Comment: "to help them transition into Linq and away from T-SQL." So, does that mean trying to move them away from Stored Procs/ADO.NET and onto Entity Framework? If so, you should be also asking for `ObjectQuery<T>` extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find hundreds of user submitted, ranked and commented extension methods on [www.extensionmethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Default.aspx) (for instance, the IEnumerable section contains 40 entries as of today).

Answer (score 3):

I started [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) - and [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) has some extra operators for LINQ to Objects as well, in System.Interactive.

(Both of these are for LINQ to Objects rather than LINQ to SQL. There's a fair amount of overlap, too.)

Just as a blatant plug, I'm likely to blog about some ideas for what else LINQ to Objects might sensibly have had as part of the wrap-up posts for my [Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx). That may or may not provide some more food for thought :)

Comment: Thanks very much. Do these methods come with any documentation, and/or examples?

Comment: @Randy: What you see is what you get for MoreLINQ :) Reactive Extensions comes with a CHM, but last I looked it wasn't very detailed. Hopefully it's been beefed up since then.