# Is there a Linq method to add a single item to an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I am trying to do something like this:

```
image.Layers
```

which returns an `IEnumerable<Layer>` for all layers except the `Parent` layer, but in some cases, I just want to do:

```
image.Layers.With(image.ParentLayer);
```

because it's only used in a few places compared to the 100s of the usual usage which is satisfied by `image.Layers`. That's why I don't want to make another property that also returns the `Parent` layer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

One way would be to create a singleton-sequence out of the item (such as an array), and then `Concat` it onto the original:

```
image.Layers.Concat(new[] { image.ParentLayer } )
```

If you're doing this really often, consider writing an `Append` (or similar) extension-method, such as the one [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645644/whats-your-favorite-linq-to-objects-operator-which-is-not-built-in/3645715#3645715), which would let you do:

```
image.Layers.Append(image.ParentLayer)
```

**.NET Core Update** ([per the "best" answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320431/3443552)):

> `Append` and `Prepend` have now been added to the .NET Standard framework, so you no longer need to write your own. Simply do this:
>
> ```
> image.Layers.Append(image.ParentLayer)
> ```

Answer (score 50):

`Append` and `Prepend` have now been added to the .NET Standard framework, so you no longer need to write your own. Simply do this:

```
image.Layers.Append(image.ParentLayer)
```

See [What are the 43 APIs that are in .Net Standard 2.0 but not in .Net Framework 4.6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601101/what-are-the-43-apis-that-are-in-net-standard-2-0-but-not-in-net-framework-4-6) for a great list of new functionality.

Comment: There is one downside to this approach vs. using `.Concat(new[] { ... })`: If the item being added also implements `IEnumerable<T>`, then the `Append` method will default to adding `IEnumerable<T>` when you might have just intended to add `T`.

Comment: Recall, however, that it doesn't operate on the original. You need to `image.Layers = image.Layers.Append(image.ParentLayer)` (and possibly `image.Layers = image.Layers.Append(image.ParentLayer).ToArray()` or similar) to get the intended effect.

Answer (score 27):

**EDIT**

Like @cpb mentioned correctly:
Append and Prepend comes out of the box now.
([source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AppendPrepend.cs))
Microsoft also decided to implement both a way to add items at the start end on the end. They created a [AppendPrepend1Iterator](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/466b0f66aafe63a31696c16dca43a727cd4bbce5/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AppendPrepend.SpeedOpt.cs) class, that has some optimizations (e.g. getting the count if the original underlying collection is an ICollection)

I'll leave my answer for historical reasons.

---

Many implementations have been given already.
Mine looks a bit different (but performs just as well)

Also, I find it practicle to also have control over the ORDER. thus often, I also have a ConcatTo method, putting the new element op front.

```
public static class Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified element at the end of the IEnummerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements the IEnumerable contans.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    /// <param name="item">The item to be concatenated.</param>
    /// <returns>An IEnumerable, enumerating first the items in the existing enumerable</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, T item)
    {
        if (null == target) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(target));
        foreach (T t in target) yield return t;
        yield return item;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the specified element at the start of the IEnumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements the IEnumerable contans.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="target">The IEnummerable.</param>
    /// <param name="item">The item to be concatenated.</param>
    /// <returns>An IEnumerable, enumerating first the target elements, and then the new element.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, T item)
    {
        if (null == target) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(target));
        yield return item;
        foreach (T t in target) yield return t;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, use an implicitly created array. (using the **params** keyword) so you can call the method to add one or more items at a time:

```
public static class Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified element at the end of the IEnummerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements the IEnumerable contans.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    /// <param name="items">The items to be concatenated.</param>
    /// <returns>An IEnumerable, enumerating first the items in the existing enumerable</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, params T[] items) =>
        (target ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(target))).Concat(items);

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the specified element at the start of the IEnumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements the IEnumerable contans.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="target">The IEnummerable.</param>
    /// <param name="items">The items to be concatenated.</param>
    /// <returns>An IEnumerable, enumerating first the target elements, and then the new elements.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, params T[] items) =>
        items.Concat(target ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(target)));
```

Comment: .NET will probably compile the yield statement to an anonymous object, which is instantiated.

Comment: @Jorrit: Actually, the compiler creates an ("anonymous") iterator, which also has some overhead. So the compiled code is bigger, but at runtime the allocated memory is a few bytes instead of a complete duplicate of the list.

Answer (score 13):

There is no single method which does this.  The closest is the `Enumerable.Concat` method but that tries to combine an `IEnumerable<T>` with another `IEnumerable<T>`.  You can use the following to make it work with a single element

```
image.Layers.Concat(new [] { image.ParentLayer });
```

Or just add a new extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value) {
  return enumerable.Concat(new [] { value });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var allLayers = image.Layers.Concat(new[] {image.ParentLayer});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
image.Layers.Concat(new[] { image.ParentLayer });
```

which concats the enum with a single-element array containing the thing you want to add

Answer (score 6):

I once made a nice little function for this:

```
public static class CoreUtil
{    
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Now this is possible:

```
image.Layers.Append(CoreUtil.AsEnumerable(image.ParentLayer, image.AnotherLayer))
```

Comment: `AsEnumerable` is now [a built-in extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as of .Net 3.5, so a different name might be in order. Additionally, `AsX` implies it's an extension method (aren't methods supposed to be a verb?), so I don't think it was a good name in the first place. I would suggest `Enumerate`.

Comment: Ha! Long ago. Yes, I came to the same conclusion in the mean time. I still use the little thing, but now it's `ToEnumerable`. `Enumerate` isn't bad either.

Comment: I still see `ToEnumerable` as suggesting an extension method. How about `CreateEnumerable`? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you like the syntax of .With,  write it as an extension method.  IEnumerable won't notice another one.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following extension methods to avoid creating a useless `Array`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value) {
   return enumerable.Concat(value.Yield());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item) {
    yield return item;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice implementation, but why avoid the array? I know it feels wrong to create the array, but is it really less efficient than all the hidden work C# does for these iterators?

Comment: Yield will allocate and return an anonymous IEnumerable<T> that holds a reference to your item, so this probably takes more memory and time than the single item array.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) method which joins two sequences.

Comment: The second element is not a sequence... that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>Concatenates elements to a sequence.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of the input sequences.</typeparam>
/// <param name="target">The sequence to concatenate.</param>
/// <param name="items">The items to concatenate to the sequence.</param>
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, params T[] items)
{
    if (items == null)
        items = new [] { default(T) };
    return target.Concat(items);
}
```

This solution is based on [realbart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019375/4961688). I adjusted it to allow the use of a single `null` value as a parameter:

```
var newCollection = collection.ConcatItems(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [C# 12 Collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) you can simply use the `..` spread operator:

```cs
        IEnumerable<int> a = [1, 2, 3]; // a can be Array, List or any IEnumerable
        IEnumerable<int> b = [..a, 4]; // Append, you can't use var here though
        IEnumerable<int> c = [0, ..a]; // Prepend
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c));
```

Interestingly I found this because the code analysis was smart enough to suggest it to me when I was trying to concat a single item with `Concat`:

```
int[] a = new[] { 0 }.Concat(b).ToArray();
// IntelliSense suggests:
int[] a = [0, ..b];
```