# How can I use System.Func?

Tags: c#, function, func

I have trouble using System.Func.

```
public Func<int> OnCreated=new Func<int>(int ASD){ Debug.Log (ASD); };
```

Is this the proper way to use it? I want to make a dynamic function that can be called. Also can the System.Func be serialized via XML?

Comment: What language are you talking about? - EDIT - tag has been added

Comment: You can not serialize functions... unless, you know, you serialize them to TypeScript, or IL.

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/q/321827/11683 for serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for `Action<>` instead?

```
Action<int> myAction = myIntParam => Debug.Log(myIntParam);
myAction(myInteger);
```

If you want to take an input parameter, and return something, you should use `Func<>`

```
Func<int, int> myFunc = myIntParam => {
   Debug.Log(myIntParam);
   return 5;
};
int five = myFunc(myInteger);
```

Also, if you want to serialize/deserialize, you need to take it one step further. Namely, by def `Func` does not really have any meaningful information for it to be serialized, you should wrap it in `Expression`. You can get started by googling for "C# serialize expression", eg: https://expressiontree.codeplex.com

Comment: [The difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate)

Comment: You can simplify it: `Action<int> myAction = p => Debug.Log(p);`

Comment: If you want to return a value you must use Func.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other thing in .NET Func is an Object. Func is an object of type Delegate.You can serialize/deserialize any serializable object. Func returns a value and can take up to 16 parameters.

The way you would use it is like this :

```
Func<int> w = new Func<int>(() => { return 1; });
```

You should first be familiar with the use of delegates. Check this : [when & why to use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates)

P.S Serializing delegates is a risky thing to do since they are pointers to functions that are inside your program.|

You can check how you can do the serialization over here : [Could we save delegates in a file (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132702/could-we-save-delegates-in-a-file-c)

Comment: "You can serialize/deserialize any object." -- No, you can't. You can only serialize/deserialize serializable objects, and which objects are serializable depends on the type of serialization that's done.

Comment: So can I serialize Functions/Actions? If no, is there a way to serialize them without XML?

Comment: @TireFruck Yes, you absolutely can do that but that's not really something you want to do in your free time.